# Find $F=\lim_{n\to \infty}F_n$ where $ F_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{x}{n}f(\frac{kx}{n}) $ and $f: [0,1]\to \mathbb R$ is continuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

> Let $f: [0,1]\to \mathbb R$ be continuous. Let us define $F_n: [0,1]\to \mathbb R$ by
>   $$ F_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{x}{n}f\left(\frac{kx}{n} \right). $$
>   Then
>
> a. Find $F=\lim_{n\to \infty}F_n$.
>   b. Show uniform convergence.

I think that the answer for a. is $\int_0^1f(x)dx$. I came up with this by showing that for each $x \in [0,1]$ $F_n(x)$ is a Riemann sum with the partition $ P=\{0 ,\frac{x}{n}, \frac{2x}{n} , \frac{3x}{n},\dots,1  \}$ and by knowing $f$ is continuous we get the integral above.

Correct me if I'm wrong.

My problem is with b. I tried showing by definition and by Cauchy definition without any success.

Comment: Note that $F$ has to be a function from $[0, 1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$, not a real number. $F$ is not in general equal to the constant function $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$:

Take $f\equiv 1$. Then
$$F_n(x) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n x = x \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} x$$
Thus, $F = \mathrm{id}$ in this case, while $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx = 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close: the limit is $\int_0^{\color{red}{x}} f(t)\, dt$. When $x = 0$, $F_n(x) = 0$, and for each $x > 0$, $F_n(x)$ is a Riemann sum for $f$ on the interval $[0,x]$.

To see that $F_n$ converges uniformly to $F$, fix $\epsilon > 0$, and using uniform continuity of $f$ on $[0,1]$, choose $\eta > 0$ such that for all $s,t\in [0,1]$, $\lvert s - t\rvert < \eta$ implies $\lvert f(s) - f(t)\rvert < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Let $N\in \Bbb N$ such that $\dfrac{1}{N} < \eta$, and write

$$\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{x}{n}f \bigl(\frac{kx}{n}\bigr) - \int_0^x f(t)\, dt = \sum_{k = 1}^n \int_{(k-1)x/n}^{kx/n} \left[f\bigl(\frac{kx}{n}\bigr) - f(t)\right]\, dt$$

If $n > N$ and $k \in \{1,2,\ldots, n\}$, $\lvert f(\frac{kx}{n}) - f(t)\rvert < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ on $[\frac{(k-1)x}{n}, \frac{kx}{n}]$. So the latter sum is bounded by

$$\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{\epsilon}{2} \frac{x}{n} = \frac{\epsilon}{2} x < \epsilon$$

Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, the result follows.

Comment: can you please explain this stage:

$$\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{x}{n}f \bigl(\frac{kx}{n}\bigr) - \int_0^x f(t)\, dt = \sum_{k = 1}^n \int_{(k-1)x/n}^{kx/n} \left[f\bigl(\frac{kx}{n}\bigr) - f(t)\right]\, dt$$

why they equal?

Comment: Each of the intervals $[(k-1)x/n, kx/n]$ has length $x/n$, so $(x/n)f(kx/n) = \int_{(k-1)x/n}^{kx/n} f(kx/n)\, dt$. Then $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n (x/n) f(kx/n) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \int_{(k-1)x/n}^{kx/n} f(kx/n)\, dt$. The integral $\int_0^x f(t)\, dt$ is divided into integrals $\int_{(k-1)x/n}^{kx/n} f(t)\, dt$, $k = 1,2,\ldots, n$. So by term-by-term subtraction, we obtain the equation above.